# Outer product vs. squaring a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

On Wikipedia, [the proof that covariance matrices are PSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) is:

[image]

I do not follow the last step. Let $\textbf{v} = \textbf{X} - \mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}]$. For a small example, then:

$$
\textbf{v} \textbf{v}^{\top} = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
v_1 v_1 & v_1 v_2 & v_1 v_3 \\ 
v_2 v_1 & v_2 v_2 & v_2 v_3 \\
v_3 v_1 & v_3 v_2 & v_3 v_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

while I interpret $\textbf{v}^2$ to be equal to

$$
\textbf{v}^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
(v_1)^2 \\ (v_3)^2 \\ (v_3)^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the $w$ and $w^T$ in there (in particular, the $w^T$ is inside of the squared term).

Comment: The quantity that is squared is a number, not a vector or a matrix

Comment: As @Damien says, $\mathbf v^2$ usually denotes the scalar product of the vector $\mathbf v$ with itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the expression in question is actually
$$w^T(\textbf{X} - \mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}])(\textbf{X} - \mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}])^Tw = (w^T(\textbf{X} - \mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}]))^2$$
To show this, observe that $w^T(\textbf{X} - \mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}])$ is the inner product of $w$ and $(\textbf{X} - \mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}])$, as such, it is a scalar (say $c$). But then
$$(\textbf{X} - \mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}])^Tw = (w^T(\textbf{X} - \mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}]))^T = c^T = c$$
as well. So their product is $c^2 = (w^T(\textbf{X} - \mathbb{E}[\textbf{X}]))^2$.